# MySql & ASP.Net database timeout problems

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database-connection

I'm hosting a site with MochaHost and I'm having problems with response time from the MySQL server.

I get a lot of ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XX.XX.XX' (10060).

MochaHost support seems to lack any knowledge of all about their services, so I'm trying to figure out a solution myself.

In order to allow a slower response time I've set the ConnectionTimeout on the odbcConnection object before opening the connection.

```
    objConn.ConnectionTimeout = 60
    objConn.Open()
```

This seems to help as the can't connect exception  does not occur that often, but I am now getting this:

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.

So it seems that I've just "relocated" the problem. Is there a setting in MySql or perhaps in the webconfig file which could solve my issue?

The site is running on a Windows shared hosting environment

Comment: check this post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1172274.aspx/1?HttpException+0x80004005+Request+timed+out+ignores+executionTimeout+

Comment: I've already set the executionTimeout="60" in the web.config. The rest seems to be parameters which is out of my reach. Since I am running on a Windows shared host environment